# Print selected value from dynamic dropdown php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below code where I can get dynamic value into drop down list from mysql db but i can't print selected value when i click on submit button.
can anyone help me urgntly ?

```
<?php
include("includes/config.inc.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM category";
$result = mysql_query ($query);
echo "<select class='turnintodropdown'  name='CategoryID' ><option value=''>All</option>";
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value=".$r['CategoryID'].">".$r['CategoryName']."</option>"; 
}
echo "</select>";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $selected_val = $_POST['CategoryID'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>  
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get Selected Values" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preselect the selected value of the  then you can use the following code. Also check your form method attrivute to see if it set to post (note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, it's better to use PDO using prepared statements).

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!empty($_POST['CategoryID']) && $_POST['CategoryID'] == $r['CategoryID']) {
        $selected = 'selected="selected"';
    } else {
        $selected = '';
    }
    echo "<option ".$selected." value=".$r['CategoryID'].">".$r['CategoryName']."</option>"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mitsarakis, but my code already working fine but i have an issue when i need to print the selected value only, please advice

Comment: Hm, what issue do you have?

Comment: already mentioned, I can't echo the below part after submitted 


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
         $selected_val = $_POST['CategoryID'];  // Storing Selected Value   In Variable
         echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected   Value
     }

Comment: you can show the full code page in the above (main question).
Every thing working fine except echo the selected value

Comment: You don't have nothing like the following: <form action="someaction.php" method="post">

Comment: Great!, Thank you very very very much Kostas.

Comment: I 'm glad that i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

from above:

```
echo "you have selected :" . $selected_val;
```

from what you are echoing, based on what I'm exp[laining], it echos the `ID`, not the name of the category.

Comment: how am i wants to display the name of the category instead of an ID.. help me please